# Matching the .NET framework versions in 2 servers

Tags: .net

We have a performance server, where I looked into registry under Microsoft -> NET Framework Setup I can see the v4 Full as below. (version 4.5.50709)

[image]

In our development server the .NET version is as below (4.6.01055)

[image]

I would like to match the .NET version in dev server with our performance server, that is to install 4.5.50709 in our dev server.

I have uninstalled .NET 4.6 framework from dev server, but it still shows the above version (screenshot 2).

Could you help me resolve this issue please?

Regards
Babu

Comment: It's possible the uninstall won't update the registry till after you reboot machine. Also, how did you go about installing .NET 4.6?

Comment: I have tried rebooting the machine. NET 4.6 was installed already in the system

Comment: How was it installed though? That could be the source of your problem. There are lots of ways to install it, but I would simply try downloading the latest offline installation for 4.6 and run it on both machines. Once completed, you should run Windows updates to get the latest patches for it, if any.

Comment: The problem is the performance server has lot of webservices and applications in stalled. So installing a new version of .NET over there is not easy requires lot of approvals and procedure. So I have to make my dev server match the .net version in performance server.

Comment: So you just want to downgrade your dev server?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Have you followed this yet: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2016/03/04/mailbag-how-to-revert-to-older-versions-of-the-net-framework-4-family/